# php function for wordpress to restrict not-logged-in-users

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

How to write a `php` function for `wordpress` to allow not-logged-in-users access only 3 pages: `mysite/login/` && `mysite/register/` && `mysite/lostpassword`  ?

I've tried with Restricted Site Access plugin

`(https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/)`,

BUT it allows me to access only login and register pages

Any ideas?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content check this out, if doesn't work when I have time I will try to write a snippt for you.

Comment: Already tried, 2 of those plugins are out to date, and breaking my site, and with the last one i can only login, you are not able to register or to reset you password

Comment: Would it not be easier both for the user and the developer if the functionality of these 3 pages were combined into one page. Then if no user is logged the server can just do a redirect to the combined page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. You will need to adjust the URL for your specific installation.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    # if user not logged in and page not login page redirect to login page
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login.php' ) === FALSE ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://.../wp-login.php' );
        exit();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Waiting for site to loading.. and nothing is happening. The code is in theme's functions.php, if I go directly to site/wp-login.php it's working - But here I have a custom login page at site/login/ - I need to go to this page every time. Somehow the wp_redirect it's not working

Comment: I actually tested my code before posting it so I know it will work at least in my environment. It is very important that the second argument to strpos() has a substring of the redirected URL. Otherwise, you will get an infinite redirection loop. Please post your actual code so I can debug it.

Comment: 'nothing is happening' - if you have an infinite redirection loop the browser will not load anything as it is repeatedly being redirected. This will happen if the second argument to strpos is not a substring of the redirected url. Specifically, you must modify the second argument of strpos to match a substring of the URL in wp_redirect.